# Int axis ticks on Google charts JS

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I want to create a LineChart that has only integers on the y-axis, since the data given is also only integer. The LineChart draws too many ticks, thus resulting in either decimal values or duplicate integers (rounded up).

I use a LineChart that is defined as follows:

```
    var time_options = {
        title: "Templates sent",
        hAxis: {
            title: 'Date',
            format:'MMM d, y'
        },
        vAxis: {
            gridlines: { count: -1},
            title: 'Templates sent'
        },
        explorer: {
            actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'],
            axis: 'horizontal'
        },
        animation: {
          startup: 'true',
          duration: 500
        },
        'tooltip' : {
            trigger: 'none'
        }
    };
```

My y-axis data consist only of integers. The resulting diagram looks like this.

[image: decimal values on y-axis]

Note the decimal values on the y axis even though the data does not contain any non integers.

I tried adding `format: '#'` but it only results in

[image: duplicate integers]

since the values are just rounded up. I read the `gridline{count:-1}` would make the ticks dynamic but it doesn't seem to affect the diagram in any way.

Basically for now I want only two ticks / gridlines for the values 1 and 2. Hardcoding the range/ticks is not an option since the values can get arbitrarily high over time.

Comment: Adding  a  'minValue: 3' "fixed" the issue for my case, but this is more of a workaround than an actual solution.